# How to deploy vm image using ovftool on vmware workstation?

Tags: vmware, ova, ovf

I am working on a python script to deploy .ova file directly to vmware workstation.

I have following question.

1. Is it possible?
2. If yes, is there any python module or ovf tool can be used for that ?

just need pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python module called pysphere which does the work for you. There is one more module called pyxenter which in turn use pysphere I guess.

I have not played around much with these packages though :-)

~S